# Detecting unexpected properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Often I use objects to pass around a set of options.

In 99.9% of these cases I expect these objects to only contain a subset of the property I use. If an unexpected property is present, it means almost always that there's a typo or a logical error.

Is there a simple way to make sure that the option objects don't contain unexpected properties? I would only really need this during testing and debugging, so it doesn't have to be efficient.

Example:

```
function log( text, opts={} ) {
    const {times=1, silent=false, logger=console} = opts
    
    if (silent) return
    
    for (let i=0; i<times; i++) {
        logger.log( text )
    }
}

// all good here
log( "Hello World!", {times:1} )

// "slient" is not a valid option. It's a typo.
// I want this call to throw an exception.
log( "Bye World!", {times:2, slient:true} )
```

I know that I can implement it through a function that receives the names of the expected properties:

```
function testOpts( opts={}, optNames=[] ) { /* ... */ }
testOpts( opts, ["times", "silent", "logger"] )
```

But maintaining this is boring and error prone: every time I change an option I need to update those parameters. I tried it and too often I forget to update it, so my function keeps accepting parameters that I removed, and this is something I want to avoid.

Is there a better solution that lets me write the property names only once?

Comment: Try using TypeScript, it's made for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to write them once, the only way to do that is in the `log` function where you are using them. There is indeed a way to do that: use [rest syntax in the destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_in_object_destructuring), and test that there are no other properties than the expected (destructured) ones:

```
function log( text, opts={} ) {
    const {times=1, silent=false, logger=console, ...rest} = opts
//                                                ^^^^^^^
    assertEmpty(rest);
    
    if (silent) return
    
    for (let i=0; i<times; i++) {
        logger.log( text )
    }
}

function assertEmpty(val) {
    const keys = Object.keys(val);
    if (keys.length) {
        throw new RangeError(`Unexpected properties ${keys.join(', ')} in object`);
    }
}
```

Other than that, use a static analysis tool such as TypeScript or Flow, they will easily catch these mistakes.

Comment: I have to use pure JavaScript, but using `...rest` is perfect. Thanks.